# динамическая переменная (ошибка в функции)

Tags: javascript

```
 var i = 0;
 var test = 'test1_test2' ;
 var testr = test.split('_');
 var test1 = 'tiiiies';
 var test2 = 'testtyty2';
 while (i < 2)
 { 
 alert( window[testr[i]])
 i++
 };
```

почему это не работает в функции выдает undefined

Comment: Не работает где именно? В консоли Хрома, например, все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у Вас этот код завернут во что-то еще (`window.onload`, `$(document).ready`, какую-нибудь другую функцию), что делает область видимости Ваших переменных не глобальной. Попробуйте убрать `var` перед `test1` и `test2`.

```js
function Test() {
  var i = 0;
  var test = 'test1_test2' ;
  var testr = test.split('_');
  test1 = 'tiiiies';
  test2 = 'testtyty2';
  while (i < 2)
  { 
    alert( window[testr[i]]);
    i++;
  };
}

Test();
```